# Postgres 'interval' syntax when the quantity comes from a calculation

Tags: postgresql

I am new to posgresql and am finding my way around. Just putting this here for general reference to anyone who comes looking for it as playing with dates and types is always time consuming.

I had issues with `interval`. Normally I use this as follows

```
select '2024-01-12'::date + interval '1 day' NextDay;  -- = 2024-01-13 00:00:00.000
```

I need to do a calculation to get the interval period to add/subtract from a date. All the below gave errors:

```
select 
      '2024-01-12'::date + interval ((8 - extract(isodow from date_trunc('year', now())::text || ' day') FirstMondayDate___GivesError_1 -- SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "("
    , '2024-01-12'::date + interval (8 - extract(isodow from date_trunc('year', now())::text || ' day' FirstMondayDate___GivesError_2 -- SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "-"
    , '2024-01-12'::date + interval '8 day' - interval extract(isodow from date_trunc('year', now())::text || ' day' FirstMondayDate___GivesError_3 -- SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "("
    , '2024-01-12'::date + interval '8 day' - interval (extract(isodow from date_trunc('year', now()))  FirstMondayDate___GivesError_4 -- SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "extract"
;
```

The snippet below works and will return the date for 1st Jan of current year and the date on the 1st Monday of the current year. The lesson here is that `interval` is a data type. The '*86400' is because the calculation result is integer seconds and there are 86400 secs in a day.

```
select 
    date_trunc('year', now())::date DateFirstJanThisYear
    , case 
        when extract(isodow from date_trunc('year', now())::date) = 1 then date_trunc('year', now())
        when extract(isodow from date_trunc('year', now())::date) > 1 then date_trunc('year', now())::date + ((8 - extract(isodow from date_trunc('year', now())::date))*86400)::text::interval
    end::date DateFirstMondayThisYear
;
```

Whoever you are, if you are looking for this, hope it saved you some time.

Comment: You can multiply the `interval` by an `int` or `numeric` directly: `select '2024-01-12'::date + '8 days'::interval - int_returning_expression * '1 day'::interval;`

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you can do it like that, but you need to add `"` double quotes: [db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/zvT6JKJg)

```sql
select '2024-01-12'::date
+"interval"((extract(isodow from date_trunc('year', now())))::text||' days');
```

It might be a bit more convenient to use the `::interval` cast:

```sql
select '2024-01-12'::date 
+((8 - extract(isodow from date_trunc('year', now())))::text||' day')::interval
```

Or multiply a `'1 day'::interval` by the expression that yields an `int`/`numeric`:

```sql
select '2024-01-12'::date 
+(8 - extract(isodow from date_trunc('year', now()))) * '1d'::interval
```

Or [`make_interval()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#id-1.5.8.15.6.2.2.30.1.1.1):

```sql
select '2024-01-12'::date 
+make_interval(days=> 8 - extract(isodow from date_trunc('year', now()))::int);
```

---

[Quoting the doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME):

> `time`, `timestamp`, and **`interval`** accept an optional precision value `p` which specifies the number of fractional digits retained in the seconds field. By default, there is no explicit bound on precision. The allowed range of `p` is from `0` to `6`.

This means when you do `interval ()`, Postgres is expecting to get the optional precision value `p` in those parentheses. You could've expected that to work because it's possible to use typed constants that way. Unfortunately, it only works for [some of the types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS-GENERIC):

> It is also possible to specify a type coercion using a function-like syntax:
>
> ```
> typename ( 'string' )
> ```
>
> but not all type names can be used in this way; see [Section 4.2.9](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS) for details.

And [in that Section 4.2.9](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS) you'll find an explicit warning:

> `interval`, `time`, and `timestamp` can only be used in this fashion if they are double-quoted, because of syntactic conflicts.

The syntactic conflict being the `p` thing.